# Camera resolution from CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions always has width > height?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, metalkit

I'm using `CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions` to get input device's (ie. camera)'s resolution:

```swift
let dimension = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(input.device.activeFormat.formatDescription)
```

The result I got aligns Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html

In which the resolutions stated are always like:

> 4032 x 3024 pixels (12 MP)

with width greater than height, can I assume it's always the case with the dimension returned by `CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions`? In other words, the resolution returned is always as if the phone is in landscape mode, regardless of the actual orientation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The camera always has a "natural" orientation since the sensor doesn't rotate inside the device when you rotate it. For all iPhone back cameras, this has been landscape so far, but it's not guaranteed to be that in the future. Also, the front camera has a natural portrait orientation, I think...

Comment: Thanks, according to Apple, both back and front cameras have landscape resolution (ie. width > height), it makes me think that the sensor is in portrait aligning with iPhone portrait orientation, and the resolution in the doc are assuming the phone is held in landscape.

Comment: Have you checked on iPad yet?

Comment: Not yet, I'll do it now.

Comment: It's the same, although my app only supports the iPhone and it's adapted on iPad in a smaller portion on the screen.